# Docker rabbitmq server is not connected to browser

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am user docker-compse.yml. I found that it is running in docker . Here is the image:
[image]

But when I am going to run  `http://localhost:15672/`,  it is not connect to rabbitmq to browser. Here is my `docker-compse.yml` . But when i run the url `http://localhost:5672/` , it shows only  `AMQP��`

```
rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8
    mem_limit: 300m
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - 'rabbitmq_data:/bitnami'
    networks:
      - account-network
    depends_on:
      - service-registry
    environment:     
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://service-registry:8761/eureka
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/

 volumes:
   rabbitmq_data:
   driver: local
```

What is the problem ? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select a RabbitMQ image, which has the management plugin included. Like this:

```
 rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
```

See [here](https://zgadzaj.com/development/docker/docker-compose/containers/rabbitmq).